# Tanstack Table & React JS: How to Show/Hide Button depend on Status when using React JS and Tanstack Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-table, tanstack

I have react js and implement tanstack table(react-table). I need help to make button/link show or hide depended on the status in each row.
Let say if there is row contain status 'Approve' the button will show, then if not it will hidden.

```
......some initiliaze data

  const [sorting, setSorting] = useState<SortingState>([]);
  const [rowSelection, setRowSelection] = useState({});
  const [isApproved, setIsApprove] = useState(false);
......calling column
const columns = useMemo<ColumnDef<IEvent>[]>(
......list of column 
{
        accessorKey: "status",
        header: () => <span>Status</span>,
        cell: (cell: any) => {
          let status = cell.getValue();
          return cell.getValue();
        },
        enableSorting: true,
        enableColumnFilter: true,
      },
      {
        accessorKey: "actions",
        header: () => <span>Action</span>,
        cell: (cell: any) => {
          console.log(isApproved);
          return (
            <div className="inline-flex gap-x-2">
              <Link to={`./${cell.row.id}/edit`}>Edit</Link>
              <EVSDeleteButton id={cell.row.id} header="event" />
              <Link to={`./${cell.row.id}/agenda`}>Agenda</Link>
            </div>
          );
        },
        enableSorting: false,
        enableColumnFilter: false,
      },
```

I hope can show/hide button('Agenda') depended status on each row

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the value of `status` from each row using `cell.row.original.status` and show the button based on the value instead of storing it in a state variable.

```
cell: (cell: any) => (
        <div className="inline-flex gap-x-2">
          <Link to={`./${cell.row.original.id}/edit`}>Edit</Link>
          {cell.row.original.status === "Approved" && (
            <Link to={`./${cell.row.original.id}/agenda`}>Agenda</Link>
          )}
        </div>
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the Ternary operator, [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator)

Comment: Yes i have, i attach my code in below
https://codepen.io/vaiz777/pen/JjemrrX

Comment: Just use {isApproved ? your (link/button) here.... : <></>}

Comment: When i use it, it only give 'false', not 'true' even there is row contain 'Approve' status. i try to dig more deep into tanstack, i have check cell properties by console.log(cell.original.status) but it give 2 status and still cannot showing or hiding button

Comment: Can I know where you are storing the status? or create a sandbox of your code

Comment: sure here is
https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-rhodes-yj9p6y?file=/src/App.js
Please ignore error about proptypes, i guess it because i am not install the dependecies

Comment: You haven't passed the isApproved as dependency in your useMemo, kindly check it

Comment: i have update it in her: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/frosty-rhodes-yj9p6y?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A119%2C16
Could you give more detail?